# How to tell if no element had a listener called for a click event

Tags: javascript, events, listener, handler

I'm trying to find a way to detect if a click event was handled by some element on the page or not.  Right now during some of our rendering, the click events are not handled. This is making it difficult for our automated testing team because they can't tell if the click events that they generate are actually being handled. Currently they have to wait for X amount of time where no changes are made to the page. This can add 1 1/2 seconds to each click which really slows down the tests.  I'd like to find a way to detect if the click was handled.  I can put a listener at the top of the dom and as the event bubbles back, it will get see it. But I can't tell if event was also handled further down in the document as well.

Can anyone think of a way to detect the difference between a top element handling the event alone, and the top element handling the event as well as the lower element, without plumbing some logic in the listeners for each of the lower elements.

I hope this makes sense,

Comment: Can you put an event listener on a test object on the page (perhaps lower right corner) and only start playing the regular click events when you are successfully getting the click on the test object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wrapping attaching event listeners in your own wrapper API, you can easily amend the event object when executing in your automated test environment.

```
function attachEventListener(node, event, handler) {
  // only do this if we are running in the test environment
  if (window.__runningAutomatedTests) {
    // wrap the event handler in a handler that will
    // amend the event object
    handler = (function(innerHandler) {
      return function(evt) {
        // invoke the actual event handler
        var result = innerHandler.apply(this, arguments);
        // amend the event object with information 
        // about that one of our event handlers handled
        // it
        evt.__wasHandled = true;

        return result;
      }
    })(handler);
  }
  node.addEventListener(event, handler);
  return function removeEventListener() {
    node.removeEventListener(event, handler);
  };
}

attachEventListener(window.document.body, 'click', function(evt) {
  if (evt.__wasHandled) {
    // event was handled by a different handler before!
  }
});
```

I don't see how this would work without hooking into the lower level event handlers.

Comment: I ended with a similar solution. I could not find a way to do it without hooking on the lower level event handlers. I was just hoping there was a native way that I didn't know about.